# How to control when Node accepts a connection on a listening `Server`?

Tags: node.js, sockets

Once `server.listen()` is called on a Node `Server`, it will start accepting connections and emitting `connection` events. I know I can stop new connections from coming in by `close()`ing the server, but is there a way for me to just let a pending connection stay pending — and perhaps eventually decide to drop it — and not have Node automatically accept the connection? I want to be able to keep the server open. That is, I don't *actually* want to close it; I just want to be able to be able to more directly decide what to do with an incoming connection and when.

The closest thing I could find was the setting `maxConnections`, but it seems like using that would force me to decide a priori — before the next would-be connection arrives — whether or not I want to accept a connection, and it would not let me do something like just keep a connection pending for a few seconds before accepting it.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netserver

Comment: *" I just want to be able to be able to more directly decide what to do with an incoming connection and when."* - based on what? Note that connections are already accepted in the OS kernel and accept (as called in node) just returns the established connection.

Comment: AIUI Node is proactively `accept()`ing and _not_ letting the kernel network stack ever see a real backlog. What I'm exploring right now is exactly how much / to what extent (and with what information) I can do connection rate limiting in userspace with Node.